# Unable to install Ubuntu 14.04 on HP Laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my HP Laptop (15 series) using ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso on a live USB.

I created the Live USB using Unetbootin utility.

I boot my laptop using the live usb. It gives me the options to either try Ubuntu or Install it. I select Installing. 
Next there is Ubuntu splash screen which stays for a while. After this a desktop environment opens with a pop-up saying that installation encountered an error and now will switch to a Desktop environment where this issue can be debugged.

I have checked the checksum of the iso, so that seems to fine.

Any help in solving this would be really nice.

Thanks.

Edit:
Ok guys. I just had a look at installation logs at `/var/log/installer/debug`.

Looks like Ubiquity ran into some problem with UPower! I am pasting the dump below:-

```
 Ubiquity 2.18.8.12
 ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.22:/org/freedesktop/UPower: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

(ubiquity:2235): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/ubuntu/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
Exception in GTK frontend (invoking crash handler):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity", line 638, in <module>
    main(oem_config)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity", line 624, in main
    install(query=options.query)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity", line 260, in install
    wizard = ui.Wizard(distro)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_ui.py", line 290, in __init__
    mod.ui = mod.ui_class(mod.controller)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-prepare.py", line 93, in __init__
    upower.setup_power_watch(self.prepare_power_source)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/upower.py", line 21, in setup_power_watch
    power_state_changed()
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/upower.py", line 18, in power_state_changed
    not misc.get_prop(upower, UPOWER_PATH, 'OnBattery'))
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/misc.py", line 823, in get_prop
    return obj.Get(iface, prop, dbus_interface=dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity", line 638, in <module>
    main(oem_config)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity", line 624, in main
    install(query=options.query)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity", line 260, in install
    wizard = ui.Wizard(distro)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_ui.py", line 290, in __init__
    mod.ui = mod.ui_class(mod.controller)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-prepare.py", line 93, in __init__
    upower.setup_power_watch(self.prepare_power_source)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/upower.py", line 21, in setup_power_watch
    power_state_changed()
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/upower.py", line 18, in power_state_changed
    not misc.get_prop(upower, UPOWER_PATH, 'OnBattery'))
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/misc.py", line 823, in get_prop
    return obj.Get(iface, prop, dbus_interface=dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

Comment: Try something other than Unetbootin, as Unetbootin is sometimes buggy. See http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows for the recommended way to create bootable Usb's

Comment: @JonasCz Thanks for the hint. Will try with that.

Comment: you can try universal usb installer, it never failed me before :)

Comment: I tried with rufus. But the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try creating the live USB using the dd command. First, you must plug in your USB drive and figure out what drive it is (/dev/sda, /dev/sdb). You could use a program like GParted or you could just use the command `fdisk -l`. You should see something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC6kt.png). I know that my USB drive is about 4 gb so my USB drive must be /dev/sdd. Next make sure that your USB drive is not mounted by using the command `umount /dev/sdx` where /dev/sdx is your USB drive. After you know this, you can use the dd command to write the image to the drive.  The command is `dd if=/path/to/file.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=512k`.  Just be sure that you don't write to a partition of the drive, or /dev/sdx1. This could result in a corruption.